# Graphite WildCard Percentage Calculation

Tags: graphite, grafana

I am working on a graph which has servers in our infrastructure, each server has a `metric1` and `metric2`, I need `metric1 / metric2`

My Grafana dashboard graph has

```
Row A : DC_Servers.*.Metric1
Row B: DC_Servers.*.Metric2
```

At this point I see all three servers and `metric1` and `metric2`. How do I get the percentage, i.e. `metric1 / metric2` on the same graph, given I have to use wild card to include all servers in DC?

Answer (score 2):

This should give you Metric1 & of Metric2 for every series (so will generate % series for the number of servers you have)

```
   reduceSeries(mapSeries(DC_Servers.*.{Metric1,Metric2},1),"asPercent",2,"Metric1","Metric2")
```

The functions reduceSeries and mapSeries are [new in Graphite 1.0.0](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releases/1_0_0.html#new-render-functions).

Comment: is there a way to use results of a groupByNode as the source of mapSeries() ?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40926039/calculate-percentage-in-graphite-for-groupbynode-results Thanks!