# Calculate percentage in Graphite for groupByNode() results

Tags: graphite, grafana

I have two groups of Graphite series, both in this format. The second group is identical, except that instead of "a.b", it has "x.y" prefix.

```
 a.b.ccc.a1.hr
 a.b.ccc.a2.hr
 a.b.ccc.a3.hr
 a.b.ddd.a1.hr
 a.b.ddd.a4.hr
```

To group by 3rd node I use `groupByNode(a.b.*.*.hr,2,"sumSeries")`, which gets me two series:  `ccc` and `ddd`.  I would like to divide `ccc` and `ddd` series from the first group by corresponding series in the second group. How do I use the result of `groupByNode` in the map/reduce function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible but tricky, or at least I don't know of an easier way to do it in an extensible way.

Note that the approach below uses `mapSeries` / `reduceSeries` functions which are only available in graphite-web `master` (not 0.9.x, see below for a manual approach that will work on 0.9.x)

We start with 2 seriesLists, that each contain `ccc` and `ddd`:

```
groupByNode(a.b.*.*.hr,2,"sumSeries")
groupByNode(x.y.*.*.hr,2,"sumSeries")
```

Now we need to get them into a single seriesList that contains all the items, so first we're going to need to make them distinguishable again:

```
aliasSub(groupByNode(a.b.*.*.hr,2,"sumSeries"), "$", ".a_b")
aliasSub(groupByNode(x.y.*.*.hr,2,"sumSeries"), "$", ".x_y")
```

Now we have `ccc.a_b`, `ddd.a_b`, `ccc.x_y`, and `ddd.x_y`, and we can get them into a single list with `group`:

```
group(
  aliasSub(groupByNode(a.b.*.*.hr,2,"sumSeries"), "$", ".a_b"),
  aliasSub(groupByNode(x.y.*.*.hr,2,"sumSeries"), "$", ".x_y")
)
```

Now we can start on the map/reduce:

```
reduceSeries(
  mapSeries(
    group(
      aliasSub(groupByNode(a.b.*.*.hr,2,"sumSeries"), "$", ".a_b"),
      aliasSub(groupByNode(x.y.*.*.hr,2,"sumSeries"), "$", ".x_y")
    ),
    0
  ),
  "asPercent", 1, "a_b", "x_y"
)
```

At this point we'll have `ccc.reduce.asPercent` and `ddd.reduce.asPercent`, you can then wrap the enire thing in another `aliasByNode(<query>, 0)` if you want just `ccc` and `ddd`.

What this is doing is essentially the same as calling:

```
group(
  alias(asPercent(
    groupByNode(a.b.ccc.*.hr,2,"sumSeries"),
    groupByNode(x.y.ccc.*.hr,2,"sumSeries"),
  ), "ccc"),
  alias(asPercent(
    groupByNode(a.b.ddd.*.hr,2,"sumSeries"),
    groupByNode(x.y.ddd.*.hr,2,"sumSeries"),
  ), "ddd")
)
```

except of course that it'll continue to work if you add `eee` etc.